# Can't access my Node.js server with external IP address

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, port-forwarding

Here are the steps I've gone through to setup my server.

I've bought an Orange Pi 5, installed Debian from their website and started to configure it.

I ordered static IP address and in Firewall/Virtual Server I added port forwarding item with this options:

- description: HTTP
- External Port: 80
- Internal Port: 80
- Internal server IP: 192.168.1.10 // the internal IP of my Orange Pi server
- Protocol: Both TCP/UDP

Then I checked with this website https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ if the port is open and it said yes.

Than I configured `nginx` to forward all requests to port 80 to `localhost:4001` where my node app is running via pm2.

Now if I try to access my node server with http://192.168.1.10 it works but when I try to access it with for example http://91.232.11.238 it times out.

Also I checked firewall and it shows something like this (which I guess shouldn't be the reason why my external requests are not reaching my Linux machine):

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want it to redirect other addresses to your own ip? You realize that https would completely break?